# Base de datos y Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2

estoy tratando de hacer un filtro en una base de datos desde un combobox, por ejemplo si en el combobox se elige sistemas en la tabla se deben de mostrar los datos de solo esa area, tengo este codigo:

```
String lugar=String.valueOf(combo.getSelectedItem());
ResultSet c=null;
try{
c=stat.executeQuery("select * from empleados where area= '"+lugar+"'");

}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

He tratado haciendolo desde un textbox pero no funciona, y ya probe de esta forma:

```
String lugar=String.valueOf(combo.getSelectedItem());

try{
stat.executeUpdate("select * from empleados where area= '"+lugar+"'");

}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona en sí? ¿Qué error estás recibiendo? ¿Qué representa `stat` en tu código?

Comment: en la linea del update cuando lo ejecuto sin en el result set, cuando lo ejecuto con el resultset (que creo que es lo mas correcto) el programa se queda trabado, y deja de correr el outpu y no me da ningun error. La variable stat es de tipo statment que ejecuta los querys

Answer (score 0):

Solo estas capturando el ResultSet, tienes que recorrerlo con un bucle, existe varios métodos como `getString​(int columnIndex)` que te permite obtener los datos del esquema ResultSet, recomiendo pasarte por este link donde encontraras la documentación necesaria.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Ejemplo:

```
while(rs.next){
     System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

como salida tendrás los valores de la posición uno de tu esquema `ResultSet`